# Page loads on local but doesn't on a host/server

Tags: html

So I've been trying some HTML templates out and I've spent 4 hours editing this certain template. It ran perfectly just for loading index.html --> Chrome.
Once I uploaded the site to my hosting I noticed that the site keeps getting stuck on the loading screen.

I wanted to past the whole index.html file but I couldn't so I uploaded it here:
http://pastebin.com/raw/P6Z2Qvd9

Since I cannot paste the whole index code here, I've also uploaded all the files to my hosting so you can view the website:

http://ziiran.xyz/notepad/

Comment: Please include all you relevant code with you question and do not only provide an external link. Not only that the external link might go away in future making you question useless for other, but also right now it could be a problem. E.g. from my destination pastebin is currently not reachable.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser and **read the error messages**.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead.